# "errMsg": "Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.hadoop.security

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I am migrating from Maven to Gradle(8.0.2) and seeing this error when I deploy my application. `gradle clean build` is successful and generating war file. I compared the gradle build with the maven, all the dependencies are same, hadoop jar is there in the `war` file under libs folder. This is how my generating war:

```
tasks.withType(Copy).all { duplicatesStrategy 'exclude' }

configurations {
implementation {
    canBeResolved = true
    canBeConsumed = true
}
}

war {
    archiveFileName = "test.war"
    webAppDirectory = file('src/main/webapp')
    classpath configurations.runtimeClasspath + configurations.implementation
}

dependencies {
// all my dependencies... 
implementation //dependencies
}
```

Can someone please help with this issue?

Comment: What do you get when you compare the contents of the 2 WARs?

Comment: WARs are exactly the same. With Gradle changes only my tomcat APIs are not working. Rest all application is working fine

Comment: If your WARs from Maven and Gradle have exactly the same contents. Literally the exact same files and file contents, then your problem is not with Gradle. If you take each of them and deploy them locally to the exact same Tomcat instance, and the Maven works and Gradle does not, then there is a difference between the two WARs that is being over looked. I would suggest unzippling both of them and comparing the two folders with Beyond Compare.